# Construct an Incidence Structure using the following axioms.

Tags: combinatorics

Right so I am fairly new to incidence structures/combinatorics and I have been asked this question that has thrown me off.

An affine plane satisfies the following 3 axioms

- Each two points are on a unique line.
- Given a point p and a line l with p not on l, there is exactly one like l' through p such that l^l' = 0. (the lines do not intersect)
- There are four points, no three of which are collinear.

Now the question asks me to construct an incidence structure that satisfies the first two axioms, but not the 3rd. I have tried but I do not see how this is possible.

Basically how I interpret the question is in order for the 3rd axiom to be broken, every 3 points must be on a line. However lets say you have 4 points, 1, 2, 3, and 4. Then for points 1, 2, 3, a line will go through them. However for points 1, 2, 4, a line must also go through them.

This means points 1 and 2 lie on two different lines, meaning axiom 1 cannot be satisfied.

So yeah am horribly misinterpreting these axioms or is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single line, and however many points you feel like having, satisfies the first two axioms. Not very interesting!

Comment: Or one point and no lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two axioms can be satisfied as follows. We have say two point $P$ and $Q$, and one line $\ell$, with $P$ and $Q$ incident on $\ell$. Then the first axiom is satisfied. So is the second. It is true that for **any** point $R$ not on $\ell$, there is a line incident on $R$ that does not meet $\ell$, for there is no such point $R$.

One can modify the example by putting any number of points on the line $\ell$.

We can make an even more trivial example by deciding that there is a single point, and no lines at all. then it is true that for any two distinct points $p$ and $Q$, there is a unique line incident on these points, for we do not have two distinct points.